# Anyone being able to run a posted Flex app

Tags: xml, security, apache-flex, cross-domain, flex4.5

This is odd and I am not sure how to ask it.
But I know that any Flex app I create that accesses/reads external data cannot be run by anyone unless they have extended a "**Trust this file**" through the “**Global Security Settings Panel**”.

Now obviously people post apps all the time that read external data that we don't have to do anything other than run the app to see.

So my question is ... what is it that I need to do to allow anyone the ability to run my app that is accessing an external data source?
I would be grateful for a pointer to the proper documentation or an explanation, thanks.

Comment: What external data source are you talking about? is it a file hosted on another domain?

Comment: How are you planning to access/read external data?  IF it's from the same domain as your compiled SWF; you should be able to use WebSErvices, HTTPService, or RemoteObject w/o making any changes to the SWF or how it is embedded or globaly flash player properties.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue.
Have you tried with crossdomain.xml file ?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- http://www.foo.com/crossdomain.xml -->
<cross-domain-policy>
    <allow-access-from domain="*"/>
    <allow-access-from domain="127.0.0.1"/>
    <allow-access-from domain="105.216.0.40"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Check the link here for more documentation.
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=security2_04.html

Comment: This is great.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Just one other question.  How do I link the xml to my swf, I mean how does the swf know that the xml is there and everything is cool?

Comment: No need to link anything here. Just drop the crossdomain.xml file on your root folder.